# how to properly enqueue styles and scripts in PHP/WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to WordPress/PHP and I'm trying to create a theme, during a tutorial it's saying to use the wp_enqueue_style/script to load css/js files however for some reason I can't seem to get Bootstrap/JQuery to work, this is my code in functions.php:

```
function rixcy_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array(), '' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'blog', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/blog.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', array('jquery'), true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rixcy_scripts' );
```

I'm also wanting to add my own custom javascript file (blog.js) but I'm unsure on how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there an error or why doesnt Bootstrap/jQuery doesnt work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes your code for adding css and js in WordPress is **correct** but you need to give **Unique Name** to each css and js

Try below code :

```
function rixcy_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array(), '' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'blog', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/blog.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', array('jquery'), true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'blog-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/blog.js', array('jquery'), true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rixcy_scripts' );
```

Comment: Great to help keep helping :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that :

```js
    wp_enqueue_script( 'blog', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/blog.js', array('jquery'), true );
```