# How to enqueue jquery script in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to load a simple jQuery script into a WP footer (using an Avada child theme). I've done it before, but nothing's happening. Can anyone spot my error?

In `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpalert' ); 
function wpalert() {
wp_register_script('wpalert', '--hardcoded root--', array ( 'jquery' ), null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('wpalert');
}
```

In my `.js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("test");
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to properly enqueue styles and scripts in PHP/WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423519/how-to-properly-enqueue-styles-and-scripts-in-php-wordpress)

Comment: What does html says? Do you see your script there? When does its loading? What error you getting in your 'js' file... so many questions.

Comment: Browsers have debug consoles.

Comment: Code turned out to be fine actually - needed to put a jquery link in Avada child theme's header.php file. I'd read that WP included jquery automatically, but apparently not.